# delete all documents from elasticsearch index in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

How can I delete all documents in Elasticsearch from index without deleting index itself?

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch("http://elasticsearch.internal:9200")

Elasticsearch.delete(es, index="index")
```

response

```
TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Is there option like truncate table in sql. I know that I can loop all ids and delete each of them but maybe there is some magic option with wildcard for example.

Comment: Elasticsearch needs to be instantiated before using it.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule it is

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Elasticsearch.delete_by_query` method can be used for deleting documents matching a query.

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete_by_query

```py
indices = ['index1', 'index2', 'other-index-names']
es.delete_by_query(index=indices, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete` method is not a static method and should be called using an instance of `elasticache.Elasticsearch`, and this way `self` will automatically be passed as an argument to the `delete` method when it is called.

Example:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()
```

Reference: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch

Secondly, as described by the elastic search documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html), "You use DELETE to remove a document from an index. You must specify the index name and document ID." Therefore, you should provide it both.

Example:

```
doc_id = "my_document"
my_index = "index"
es.delete(id=doc_id, index=my_index)
```

Reference: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete